# Apache2 - why "http://localhost/index" redirect to "http://localhost/index.php"?

Tags: php, configuration, apache2

My current environment is: Debian, apache2 & php5.

When I browse `"http://localhost/index"`, the `"http://localhost/index.php"` script is executed.

If I don't want to do this, do I need to change apache's configuration? If yes, how I can do that?

Comment: Can you post your virtualhost or .htaccess file for localhost (default domain)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by apache's MultiViews directive.
Refer to the documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html#multiviews